# prevent to input string or integer value

Tags: php

This is the PHP code and I want to check if an invalid value is present:

```
$response = $_POST['response'];
$visibility = $_POST['visibility'];


if($response == NULL || $visibility == NULL ){
    printf("Invalid input: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    echo "<br/><a href='myevents.php'>Back to previous page</a>";
    exit();
}
```

`$response` and `$visibility` should be the integer value 
so If people put the string value I want to go to the  `if($response == NULL || $visibility == NULL )` statement. 
How to write the statement `$response == ???`

Answer (score 1):

Using `is_numeric` will provide the desired result. `is_numeric` finds whether the given variable is numeric

```
if (!is_numeric($response) || is_numeric($visibility))
 echo "Invalid input";
```

Some people suggest `is_int()`. Don’t use `is_int()`. Use is_numeric() instead.

Copy the following chunk of code into a php file and run it. You’ll be surprised at the outcome:

```
$t = "12345";
if( is_int($t ) ) {
    echo $t . " is an int!";
} else {
    echo $t . " is not an int!";
}
```

The problem is that `is_int()` thinks a string of numbers is a string, not an integer.

The key difference between the two is the one checks the type of variable, `is_int()`, and the other checks the value of the variable, `is_numeric()`.

Comment: How is there some function for string value?

Comment: @Lee what do you want exactly

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `is_nan()` function,

```
if(is_nan($response) || is_nan($visibility)){
    printf("Invalid input: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    echo "<br/><a href='myevents.php'>Back to previous page</a>";
    exit();
}
```

```
var_dump(NAN == NAN); // boolean true
var_dump(NAN === NAN); // boolean true
var_dump(is_nan(NAN)); // boolean true

var_dump(NAN == 12); // boolean true
var_dump(NAN === 12); // boolean false
var_dump(is_nan(12)); // boolean false

var_dump(NAN == 12.4); // boolean true
var_dump(NAN === 12.4); // boolean true
var_dump(is_nan(12.4)); // boolean false

var_dump(NAN == NULL); // boolean true
var_dump(NAN === NULL); // boolean false
var_dump(is_nan(NULL)); // boolean false

var_dump(NAN == 'K<WNPO'); // boolean true
var_dump(NAN === 'K<WNPO'); // boolean false
var_dump(is_nan('K<WNPO')); // null and throws a warning "Warning: is_nan() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in NANTest.php on line 13"
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-nan.php

Answer (score 0):

try `is_numeric` or `is_int`

Follow these links:

http://php.net/is_int

http://www.php.net/is_numeric

Comment: Nope. is_int() finds whether the type of the given variable is integer. To test if a variable is a number or a numeric string (such as form input, which is always a string), you must use is_numeric().